# How to get Active Record id from data rendered in view passed back to the controller (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, view, controller

I'm working on a Rails 4.1.9 app that has three models— User, Device, and UserDevice.  In the view, there is an each loop to display a table of all the devices that belong to a user (We use slim not erb, so this is the HTML):

```
- @user.devices.each do |device|
  tr
    td= device.id
    td= device.name
    td= device.device_type
```

It's my task to add a way to delete the UserDevice association if a delete button is clicked, so I added the following code:

In view:

```
td= link_to "Clear device", [:clear_device, :admin, @business, @user], method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-flat danger'
```

In controller:

```
def clear_device
  device = UserDevice.where(user_id: params[:id])
  device.destroy_all

  redirect_to admin_business_user_path
end
```

The issue I'm running into is that when I query for the device that matches the user_id, there can be multiple devices, which is why I have to use destroy_all, even though I only want to destroy one. What I need is for the id from the first column in the table to be passed back to the controller so that I can query for both the device_id and user_id, like so:

```
 def clear_device
   device = UserDevice.where(device_id: (id from view) AND user_id: params[:id])
   device.destroy

   redirect_to admin_business_user_path
 end
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get that id from the table in the view back to the controller though, any suggestions? I know that its possible if I were to use a hidden field in a form, but that seems to not be best practice if I don't actually use the form for anything. I would also prefer not to bring in any JavaScript or jQuery, but I will if that's the only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track and are really close.  I don't know what your routes.rb looks like, but I'm guessing the way your routes are set up, it is assumed that params[:id] maps to a user_id.  You just need to send up an extra parameter with your "Clear Device" that includes a device_id.  I'm not too familiar with slim, so this syntax might not be exact:

```
td= link_to "Clear device", admin_business_clear_device_path(id: @user.id, device_id: device.id), method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-flat danger
```

Look at your routes and path helpers to figure it the correct link destination.  ERB would look something like this:

```
<td><%= link_to "Clear Device", {:controller => :admin, :action => :clear_device, :id => @user.id, :device_id => device.id}, {:method => :delete, :class => 'btn btn-flat danger'} %></td>
```

There are several different ways to write this, but you should definitely be able to pass up an extra query string parameter: device id.  Then in your controller you can do exactly what you want by accessing params[:device_id]:

```
def clear_device
  device = UserDevice.where(device_id: params[:device_id] AND user_id: params[:id])
  device.destroy

  redirect_to admin_business_user_path
end
```

Hope this helps.